# How do you duplicate all UDP traffic on a port range using nftables

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, routing, nftables

I'm trying to get all traffic on port 8000-8900/udp to be copied to another port range, or another virtual device for measuring latency between multiple sources.

I'm aware `iptables` has a TEE option, however the examples I've found haven't worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DaemonLogger](https://github.com/Cisco-Talos/Daemonlogger/), a tool developed by Sourcefire founder, Martin Roesch. Basically this tool creates a soft TAP where you can copy packets to. In your case, the important switches will be `-i` for input interface to sniff from and `-o` for output interface to spit packets to.

You can create a dummy interface if you don't want to use loopback, which I think it is recommended especially when you want to avoid contaminating packet captures for analysis. In this example, I will create a dummy interface named `dummy0` and assign and IP address of `192.168.1.150/24`.

```
$ sudo modprobe dummy
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "dummy" >> /etc/modules'
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "
auto dummy0
iface dummy0 inet static
address 192.168.1.150
netmask 255.255.255.0" >> /etc/network/interfaces'
```

Then you can now run `daemonlogger`, assuming that your physical interface is `eth0`

```
$ sudo daemonlogger -i eth0 -o dummy0
```

Reference: https://talosintelligence.com/daemon

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for pointing out. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to create another destination address to duplicate packets to.

```bash
sudo ip addr add 10.0.0.1/24 dev lo
```

In this example, we match udp packets coming on ports 8000 to 8100 from any non-loopback interface to avoid an infinite packet cycle. The packets duplicated and forwarded to the interface that routes to 10.0.0.1. Note that the packets have not been modified at this point, and still retain the original source and destination addresses.

Afterwards, we filter separately filter any packets on the loopback interface and set the destination ip address to itself, so debugging tools can listen on 10.0.0.1:8000-8100 and receive the packets.

```bash
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

table ip mangle {
    chain prerouting {
        type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        iifname != lo udp dport 8000-8100 dup to 10.0.0.1 device lo notrack
    }

    chain input {
        type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
        iifname lo udp dport 8000-8100 ip daddr set 10.0.0.1 notrack
    }
}
```

Example command to listen to packets: `nc -v -k -u -l 10.0.0.1 8000`

To clean up, run

```bash
sudo ip addr delete 10.0.0.1/24 dev lo
sudo nft flush ruleset
```

In the screenshot, host 192.168.1.50 sends a packet to 192.168.1.2:8000, and it is duplicated. The application on 192.168.1.2:8000 responded to the sender. Note that wireshark does not show the updated destination address.

[image: Wireshark log]